# Selecting rows on base of two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got 2 tables

event:

```
id| id_event| id_user | data
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1       2         4     20.08.2012
2       2         5     20.08.2012
3       2         6     20.08.2012
```

rating:

```
id | id_event | id_user_who's rate  | id_user_which get rate    | rate
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1         2           4                        5
```

What I want to achieve is select users which took part in same event where `id_user` is equal to `id_user_login` and they were not been rated by him yet.

So like on the example above `id_user_login` number 4 rated user number 5 so I need query which will give me back user 6

**edit**

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM event as ev WHERE ev.id_user not in ( select $log1[id] union all SELECT id_user_whos_rate FROM event as e INNER JOIN rating as r on r.id_event = e.id_event WHERE e.id_user = $log1[id])
```

I've tried this one and as return I received all users from event table for id_user_login while one of user was already rated so he shouldn't be display.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a SQL query generation service. What have you tried? What results did you get, and what results did you expect?

Comment: $a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM event as ev 
WHERE 
ev.id_user not in ( 
select $log1[id] union all 
SELECT id_user_whos_rate FROM event as e 
INNER JOIN rating as r on r.id_event = e.id_event 
WHERE e.id_user = $log1[id])
I've tried this one and as return I received all users from event table for  id_user_login while one of user was already rated so he shouldn't be display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.id_user
FROM    `event` a
        LEFT JOIN rating b
            ON  a.id_event = b.id_event AND
                a.id_user = b.id_user_which_get_rate
WHERE   a.id_user <> 4 AND
        EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    `event` c
            WHERE   a.id_event = c.id_event AND
                    c.id_user = 4
        ) AND
        b.id IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c68d9/5)

Table `event` is joined with table `rating` via columns: `id_event` and `id_user` using `LEFT JOIN`. It is joined on two columns inorder to select only rows that belong to a user in a particular event.

The purpose of the `WHERE` clause is exclude the current user from the result list. The `EXISTS` filters only `event` for a particular current user who logged in.

Comment: That's great, working exactly how I want it but it just wondering me 
one more think how should display it like this id_event, id_user, id_user....id_event, id_user.... because when I'm doing like that:
while($b = mysql_fetch_array($a)){ 
echo 
$b[id_event}
$b[id_user]
it's displaying seperate each of the users by same id_event like 2 - user1 , 2 - user 2, 2 - user 3 , and I rather prefer 2 - id_user1, id_user2, id_user3